# If element exists by data attribute

Tags: angularjs

I have a number of spans being created with ng-repeat:

```
<div class="row" id="year-1">
    <span class="event" ng-repeat="(key, event) in events" event data-start={{event.date_start}} data-end={{event.date_end}} data-key={{key}} data-type={{event.role}}>
        {{event.title}} - {{event.date_start}}
    </span>
</div>
```

I have a directive for event which does a number of things to manipulate each span created accordingly. One of the things is to check is there are other spans with data-type="X".

In my directive, if I do the following, I get all the span's with class 'event':

```
var parentid = angular.element(document.getElementById('year-1'));
var typeExists = parentid[0].querySelectorAll('.event')[0];
```

But if I try to narrow it down to data-type="X" such as the following, I get undefined.

```
var typeExists = parentid[0].querySelectorAll('.event[data-type="' + attr.type + '"]')[0];
```

Am I overlooking something? Full directive:

```
angular.module("app").directive("event", function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            var getStart    = attr.start.split('-'),
                getEnd      = attr.end.split('-'),
                getKey      = attr.key;
                getHeight   = element[0].offsetHeight;

            var parentid = angular.element(document.getElementById('year-1')),
                backgroundParent = angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName('year-current'));

            // get the month event starts with
            var monthStart = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('[data-location="' + getStart[1] + '"]'));

            // get the month event ends with
            var monthEnd = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('[data-location="' + getEnd[1] + '"]'));

           // how many events do we have
            var eventcount = angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName('event'));

            // get width of events container
            var eventsContainer = angular.element(document.getElementById('events'));

            // does this type exist already, if so get its top 
            var typeExists = parentid[0].querySelectorAll('.event')[0];
            console.log(typeExists);

            if(monthStart.length > 0) {

                // how many days in start month
                var daysStart = getDaysInMonth(getStart[1], getStart[0]),
                    daysStartPercent = (getStart[2] / daysStart.length);

                // how many days in end month
                var daysEnd = getDaysInMonth(getEnd[1], getEnd[0]),
                    daysEndPercent = (getEnd[2] / daysEnd.length);

                // determine left starting %
                var elementLeft = ((monthStart[0].offsetLeft + (monthStart[0].clientWidth * daysStartPercent)) / eventsContainer[0].clientWidth) * 100;

                // determine width in %
                var elementRight = ((monthEnd[0].offsetLeft + (monthEnd[0].clientWidth * daysEndPercent)) / eventsContainer[0].clientWidth) * 100;
                var width = (elementRight - elementLeft);

                // get the background color for this role
                var background = angular.element(document.querySelector('.role[data-type="' + attr.type + '"]'))[0].getAttribute('data-background');

                element.css({
                    'left': elementLeft + '%',
                    'top' : parentid[0].offsetHeight + 'px',
                    'width': width + '%',
                    'background': background
                });

                element.addClass('stretchRight');

                parentid.css({'height': parentid[0].offsetHeight + getHeight  + 'px'});
                backgroundParent.css({'height': parentid[0].offsetHeight + getHeight  + 'px'});



            } else {
                element.css({ 'display': 'none' });
            }


        }
    }
});
```

Comment: why are you searching the dom and not your data model? *"Am I overlooking something"* ... yes ... you need to account for `ng-repeat` rendering. Please provide [mcve]

Comment: Searching dom because I'm trying to find the location (position: absolute) of the previous span where data-type="X"... This way I can apply this position (with some minor adjustments) to this next span.

Comment: still too many unknowns. Update question with full details and directive code. Seems like you would want to run this in a parent directive but still not clear what objective is

Comment: main issue you will run into is timing...try wrapping it all in `$timeout` to start to allow ng-repeat to render and defer your code to next digest. if the data is being modified later though you will need more advanced strategy

Comment: @charlietfl thank you. wrapping in $timeout seemed to do the trick. Not sure if you want to put as answer.

Comment: but yeah, I'm seeing what you mean already about needing a more advanced strategy.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to recreate the problem you saw and found that you need to change your line from this:

```
var typeExists = parentid[0].querySelectorAll('.event[data-type="' + attr.type + '"]')[0];
```

to this:

```
var typeExists = parentid.querySelectorAll('.event[data-type="' + attr.type + '"]')[0];
```

Remove the `[0]` from your `parentid` reference because you only have a single element with ID of `year-1` which means it's not an array.

Comment: `angular.element()` returns a jQlite object...not dom nodes